# Writing the content of a RichTextBox to a file

Tags: c#, richtextbox, iostream, newline

I have a RichTextBox and I want to save the text to a file. Each line of the RichTextBox are ended with CR+LF ("\n\r") but when i save it to a file, the lines only contains the LF char at the end.

If I copy the content to the clipboard instead of a file all goes right (The content of the clipboar has CR+LF at the end of each line, I can see it when I paste in Notepad++). txtClass is the RichTextBox.

private void btnToClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Works as desired
        Clipboard.SetText(txtClass.Text);
    }

```
private void btnToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Don't work as desired
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();             
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, false, Encoding.ASCII);              
        SW.Write(txtClass.Text);            
        SW.Close();
    }

}
```

At this moment, I also tried with

```
SW.NewLine = "\r\n";
SW.Newline = Environment.NewLine
```

and with all Enconding avalilables.

If I use 
SW.Write("Line One\r\nLineTwo\r\nLineThree") also works fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try the SaveFile method located on the RichTextBox itself?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(VS.71).aspx

Comment: txtClass.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); 
Worked Perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan- could you add Mr.Lindholms answer to this question and mark it as an answer? I've bumped into your question twice now since its still not answered :)

Comment: @Peter Lillevold - Of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Lindholm, who gave me the correct answer in a comment.

> Did you try the SaveFile method
>   located on the RichTextBox itself?
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - but didn't want to save as a RichTextBox - just a standard simple txt file that could easily be read and edited in notepad.

The issue is for some reason the StreamWriter class does NOT write the \n into the file (still not sure why - you would think it would) :)

So a simple solution is to manually replace \n with \r\n and works perfect as expected.

See code snipit below:

```
if ((myStream = ScriptFileSaveDB.OpenFile()) != null)
{
    using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(myStream))
    {
        //Since \n (newlines) are not being written correctly as \r\n
        //Go thru Text and replace all "\n" with \r\n
        tempStr = ScriptProgramWindowRTB.Text;
        tempStr = tempStr.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
        sr.Write(tempStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Don't work as desired
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
            saveFileDialog1.FileName, false, Encoding.ASCII);
        SW.Write(txtClass.Text);
        SW.Close();
    }
}
```